# image no show on page when I run project springboot

Tags: java

I have a project java with springboot and when I try show the image on the web page, it doesn't work, it show error is no endpoint GET image/image.png and no mapping for GET image/image.png someone help me

I've tried to show the image in several ways and it still doesn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4LJb.png)

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of code required to answer your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.